# Is there a way that the :reserved_words option for models in FriendlyId gem does not overwrite the Rails defaults?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have the default friendly_id configuration in place in my project, which without comments looks like this:

```rb
FriendlyId.defaults do |config|
  config.use :reserved

  config.reserved_words = %w(new edit index session login logout users admin stylesheets assets javascripts images)
end
```

And a model which has this configuration:

```rb
EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES = %w(users articles authors topics admin your all)

friendly_id :name, use: :slugged, reserved_words: EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES
```

This is because the model is accessible through this route: `/:id`

My problem is that the model configuration overwrites the defaults in the config file. I can create the model with a `name: 'new'` and the slug will be set to `'new'`, while it will not work for other models.

I wasn't expecting this to be the default behaviour. Is there a way to have the defaults active while adding specific reserved words to a model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each model that extends `FriendlyId` gets its own copy of the friendly_id configuration that you can manipulate. You can access (and modify) this configuration using `friendly_id_config`.

So you could `concat` your additional list of `EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES` onto the `reserved_words`, like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES = %w(users articles authors topics admin your all)
  friendly_id_config.reserved_words.concat(EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES)
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

All of your models will continue to use the reserved words you specified in the default configuration, and `MyModel` will additionally reserve `EXCLUDED_SLUG_VALUES`.